# cumulative sum of list ignoring duplicated elements in O(n)

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, cumulative-sum

Is there a way to print the cumulative sum of a given list of non-negative integers of length n in O(n)?

For instance, given a list {3,2,3,12,2}

the  output would be: 3 5 5 17 17

I would have to implement this in a unbounded ram, so complicated structures may be hard to do.

Comment: @KaziSohan for this output, the list is {3,2,3,12,2}, because we are ignoring all duplicated element

Comment: What can be the maximum value of the array?

Comment: @KaziSohan there's no restriction on the max value

Comment: You have to somehow understand which numbers are duplicates. You can use ```map``` type structures which will mostly take ```O(lg n)```. So I don't think there is any way to do it in ```O(n)```

Comment: @KaziSohan I have implemented this using tries, which is O(nlogm), m being the longest element. I have been given that it's possible to do it in O(n), but I have no clue where to start

Comment: If you are using ```python```, you can use python ```dict```. It's average complexity is ```O(1)```. So using it, overall complexity will be very close to ```O(n)```

Comment: @KaziSohan I'm using racket and the only data structure allowed to store is a unbounded ram, which is like an array that can store and output integers of any index in O(1). Is it possible to implement something like dict in this?

Comment: What is the maximum array size you can declare in racket?

Comment: @KaziSohan The size is infinite, and I can define the value at any index when ever I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a HashSet for the lookup of already seen elements then you just need a single pass and can solve this in `O(n)`.

```
def cumulative_sum(l):
    seen = set()
    result = []
    for e in l:
        last = result[-1] if result else 0
        if e in seen:
            result.append(last)
        else:
            seen.add(e)
            result.append(last + e)
    return result

l = [3, 2, 3, 12, 2]
print(cumulative_sum(l))
```

Comment: Hi, I just did some research on Hash Tables. Correct me if I'm wrong, the average time complexity is O(1), but in the worst case, it could go up to O(n)?

Comment: It can go up to `O(n)` if the hash function maps all your values to the same few buckets. There are cases like this in practice, but it's usually when people write their own hash functions.